# Add active class to element in nested ngFor Angular 6

Tags: angular, radio-button, ngfor

I would like to add active class after click, and I have problem with ngFor inside ngFor. When I clik on one radio, active class is added to all rows, because is the same name. Besides, now I can click only for one radio, I want to click for one radio in the row (I do not know how to make a radio independent of each other between the rows)

I want to add active class independent between rows, so eg I want to selected test1 from Lorem, test2 from Ipsum and test1 from dolor. Now I can choose only one radio from all elements.

My example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aupnma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot create property 'selectedTest' on string 'test1' - problem with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210735/cannot-create-property-selectedtest-on-string-test1-problem-with-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- Your radios do not have a common name for each test (so that can only select one in total)
- You only keep one selected item, so you can only ever apply the class to one item)

Modify component.ts to save selected itemS

```
selectedItems = {};
  selectItem(item, id) {
    this.selectedItems[id] = item;
      }

  isSelectedItem(item, id) {
    return this.selectedItems[id] && this.selectedItems[id] === item;
  };
}
```

Modify your template to add a common name to your radios and change the check for active class

```
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          *ngFor="let item of test.items"
          (click)="selectItem(item,test.id)"
          [ngClass]="{active: isSelectedItem(item, test.id) }">
          <input
          type="radio"
          name="something_{{test.id}}"/>
          {{item}}
        </label>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gih1fl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE** as  Ali Shahbaz suggested to group the checkbox inputs

You can try something like this
in app.component.html

```
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let test of tests">
      <input type="checkbox"
        id="">
        {{test.name}} 
      <div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          *ngFor="let item of test.items"
          (click)="selectItem(item,test.id)"
          [ngClass]="{active: isSelectedItem(item) && selectedId==test.id}">
          <input
          type="radio"
          name="something{{test.id}}"/>
          {{item}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  tests: any[];
  selectedItem: any;
  selectedId:number;

  constructor() {
    this.tests = [{
      id: 1, name: 'lorem', items: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
    },
    {
      id: 2, name: 'ipsum', items: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
    },
    {
      id: 3, name: 'dolor', items: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
    }]

  }

  selectItem(item,id) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    this.selectedId=id;
  }

  isSelectedItem(item) {
    return this.selectedItem === item;
  };
}
```

Comment: ok, it solve problem with active class but still is a problem with independent radio button. I would like to can selected eg test1 from Lorem, test2 from Ipsum and test1 from dolor. Now I can choose only one radio from all elements.

Comment: Set name for the element like this `name="something{{test.id}}"`